# What does the compare function look like in ocaml?

Tags: list, sorting, compare, ocaml

I am trying to use List.sort on a char list list list where the inner most list is representative of a word and I can use the compare compare function to sort the inner most by alphabetical order. I'm wondering what the compare function looks like? It has type 'a -> 'a -> int.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so `char list` is a word, and `char list list` is word list. You are sorting a list of word lists. What is alphabetical order for word lists? Which comes first, "biker" or "bike shorts"? Dictionaries don't agree on the order.

If you want "bike shorts" to come first, this is (recursive) lexicographic order.

It so happens that the built-in polymorphic `compare` uses lexicographic order. So you could just use it straight out of the box:

```
# List.sort compare [[['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e'; 'r']];
  [['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e']; ['s'; 'h'; 'o'; 'r'; 't'; 's']]];;
- : char list list list =
[[['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e']; ['s'; 'h'; 'o'; 'r'; 't'; 's']];
 [['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e'; 'r']]
```

If you want to write your own compare function it's just a function with two parameters of the type you want to sort. To sort lists of words in an order that ignores spaces between words you could use this compare function:

```
let catcompare a b = compare (List.concat a) (List.concat b)

# List.sort catcompare [[['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e']; ['s'; 'h'; 'o'; 'r'; 't'; 's']];
  [['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e'; 'r']]];;
- : char list list list =
[[['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e'; 'r']];
 [['b'; 'i'; 'k'; 'e']; ['s'; 'h'; 'o'; 'r'; 't'; 's']]]
```

If what you're saying is that you want to sort the inner lists, then the question isn't about the comparison function. You can use the same built-in `compare`. The real question is how to apply a function to all the elements of a list and collect up the results into a list. (I'll leave this as an exercise. If you're already using `List.sort` you should know where to look for possible ideas.)